# I have 6 frames I want to resize using button click

Tags: jquery, html

I have six frames. I want to do when I click on button which is in middle frame then middle frame size increase or decrease. But problem here is that button tag is not working in frame tag. I want to increase width and height both of middle frame. How can I do this?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML Frameset DTD>


<head>
    <script src="http://localhost:55980/Scripts/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>

<!--<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">
function getFrameSize(frameID) {
    var result = {height:0, width:0};
    if (document.getElementById) {
        var frame = parent.document.getElementById(frameID);
        if (frame.scrollWidth) {
            result.height = frame.scrollHeight;
            result.width = frame.scrollWidth;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
</script>-->
</head>
    <frameset rows="42,*" cols="*">
    <frame src="menu_bar.html" name="topmenu" noresize="noresize" marginwidth="20">
    <frameset rows="*" cols="33%,33%,33%" border="20" bordercolor="silver">
    <frameset rows="25%,25%,25%" framespacing="2" border="2" bordercolor="2">
        <frame Id="frameID" name="google" src="frame_a.html" marginwidth="20">
        <frame src="frame_b.html" marginwidth="20">             
        <frame src="frame_c.html" marginwidth="20">
    </frameset>
    <frameset rows="25%,25%,25%" framespacing="2" border="2" bordercolor="2">
        <frame src="frame_d.html" marginwidth="20">
        <frame id="frameE" src="frame_e.html" marginwidth="20">
        <noframe>
           <button type="button"id="button">resize</button>
        </noframe>                         
        <frame src="frame_f.html" marginwidth="20">
    </frameset>
    <frameset rows="25%,25%,25%" framespacing="2" border="2" bordercolor="2" id="foo">
        <frame src="frame_g.html"  marginwidth="20">
        <frame src="frame_h.html" Id="idFrame"  marginwidth="20">
                    <frame src="frame_i.html"  marginwidth="20">
    </frameset>
    </frameset>
    </frameset>
<script>
    $("#button").click(function () {
        var maxHeight = 300; 
        var maxwidth = 300;

        if (+$('#frameE').height() && +$('#chartdiv').width() < maxHeight) {

            $('#frameE').stop().animate({ height: 300,width:300, opacity: 1 }, 'slow');

        } else if (+$('#frameE').height() && +$('#chartdiv').width() === maxHeight) {

            $('#frameE').stop().animate({ height: 50,width:50, opacity: 1 }, 'slow');

        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: your button is within a `<frameset>` and a `<noframe>` tag. But `<noframe>` is not a valid tag. It should be `<noframes>`. But then the button will only render if the frames don't. I think the `<button>` needs to be outside the `<frameset>` entirely. By the way I hope this is not new code because framesets and frames are no longer supported in HTML5

Comment: also I can't see any indication that the `height` attribute is valid for a frame. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/frame and https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/present/frames.html

Comment: to change the height of the frames you'd need to alter the `rows` attribute of the parent frameset